# Combine multiply numpy columns into one for multi-label classification

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a array of multiple columns where each column represents a dummy variable. I need to combine all columns into a single vector to prepare for a multi-label classification. So an array of nx6 needs to turn into an array of nx1

for example:

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.]])
```

should look like:

```
array([[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  1.],
       [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.],
       [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.]])
```

Right now I have six columns but I wanted to generalize the code for an array of any number of columns since I'm not sure how many labels we are going to end up using.

So far I've tried numpy.column_stack but that's still giving me an array of shape nx6. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Where's the expected `nx1` array?

Comment: You're right, my formatting was not correct for the second array. Is it possible to have an array of shape nx1 with a vector of numbers for each row?

Comment: Not in a regular array.

Comment: It is possible make an array of objects, where the objects are 1d arrays or lists.  But I'm not sure that will be superior to this 2d array.  Tell us more about this 'multi-label classification` task.

Comment: I'm using scikit learn to build a model to predict movie genres (where a given movie can have multiple genre labels). I was told that scikit learn can handle these types of problems but the Y should be in the form of a vector of dummies where the dummy is turned on if the movie has that label. When I attempt to train a model on an outcome Y that is any wider than a nx1 array, I get an error that says bad input shape so I was thinking this is why I need it to be in the shape of nx1.

Comment: You could try to convert each row to a scalar each with their decimal equivalents. For example the second row in the sample becomes 3 and so on.

Comment: Double check this, but I think the `Y` vector must be a simple dtype like boolean or integer.  So that 'turned on' value is a simple 0/1 or False/True.  It doesn't work to try replace it with a 'list' or 'array', i.e many values.  In other words, one feature, not 6 features, or 6 somehow 'compressed' into 1.

Comment: Is this the relevant `sklearn` doc page? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html